# Rails: How to render form inside form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which contains business cards, each card has a checkbox and user can select them and submit them.

When user clicks on `edit` button a modal with an edit form will pop up. Here comes my problem: I can't have a form inside a form.

I don't know what is the best approach for this problem. The code (that doesn't work) looks something like this:

```
<%= form_tag submit_names_path, method: "GET" do %>
  <% @names.each do |name| %>
    <div class="name-card">
      <%= name.first_name %>
      <%= name.last_name %>
      <%= name.telephone %>
      <input id="name_ids[<%= name.id %>]" type="checkbox" value="<%= name.id %>" name="name_ids[]">
      <label for="name_ids[<%= name.id %>]"> select </label>
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="name-modal-<%= name.id %>"> edit </a>

      <div id="name-modal-<%= name.id %>" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
        <%= form_for name do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :telephone %>
          <%= f.submit "Complete Edit %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_tag "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm by no means a Rails expert, but a form within a form would indeed be invalid HTML. What you'd need to do is have your `<div>` modal code outside of the core `<form>` element, and then reference it so it opens the relevant modal on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this situation you need separated loops.

```
<%= form_tag submit_names_path, method: "GET" do %>
  <% @names.each do |name| %>
    <div class="name-card">
      <%= name.first_name %>
      <%= name.last_name %>
      <%= name.telephone %>
      <input id="name_ids[<%= name.id %>]" type="checkbox" value="<%= name.id %>" name="name_ids[]">
      <label for="name_ids[<%= name.id %>]"> select </label>
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="name-modal-<%= name.id %>"> edit </a>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  <%= button_tag "SUBMIT" %>
 <% end %>
 <% @names.each do |name| %>
  <div id="name-modal-<%= name.id %>" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
      <%= form_for name do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :telephone %>
        <%= f.submit "Complete Edit %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```